# sudo permission denied on nmcli : ubuntu server 64 raspberry pi 3

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

I have freshly installed and updated ubuntu on raspberry pi 3.

Neither `sudo ls` nor `sudo apt-get install` pose any problem, but executing:

```
sudo nmcli device status
```

gives:

> Error: Could not create NMClient object: Could not connect: Permission denied

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I'm seeing the same when trying to do anything with `sudo apt`

Comment: @DaveStephens, i did not.  I gave up and went with raspbian

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I fixed it with `snap connect network-manager:nmcli` as described in [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/snap.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have Network-Manager installed as a Snap, and the Snap's CLI plug has not been granted permissions.  You can solve the problem by running `snap plug network-manager:nmcli`.